# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a factory to create the request context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tiles, thymeleaf

I am tiring to use spring boot,thymeleaf and tiles in my project ,but i just keep getting the titled error.

stacktrace error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a factory to create the request context
    at org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory.createRequestContext(ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:317)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.view.ThymeleafTilesView.render(ThymeleafTilesView.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>Supporter</groupId>
    <artifactId>Supporter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Supporter</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.test.supporter.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
    </properties>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The Configration class

```
@Configuration
public class Configurations {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        Set<TemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        templateResolvers.add(webTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
        Set<IDialect> additionalDialects = new HashSet<>();
        additionalDialects.add(new TilesDialect());
        templateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(additionalDialects);
        return templateEngine;
    }

     @Bean
        public ServletContextTemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {
            ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
            templateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/tiles/templates/");
            templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
            templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
            templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            templateResolver.setOrder(2);
           return templateResolver;
        }
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-defs.xml" });
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return configurer;
    }
    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class);
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);//ADDED LINE
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

**Note that :**  also i have tried to changed the versions of libraries but i got **NoClassDefError** and tried **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf** but no luck .so can any one help please?

Comment: can you add the stack trace?

Comment: @RishiKeshPathak thanks for the response i just add it

Comment: Missing `tiles-core`, `tiles-template`, `tiles-jsp` and `tiles-servlet` dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: @WundwinBorn tiles-extras downloaded them to the lib, but any way i just remove it and put your dependency but nothing changed

Comment: try with All tiles Jars version 2.2.2 and Spring 3.0.7 jar, see if issue persists. be careful while adding jars, it gives NOClassDefError If not added properly.

Comment: @RishiKeshPathak as far as i noticed spring-boot download only spring 4 libraries

Comment: if you are using spring 4 , will suggest you to use tiles 3 with it.

Comment: @RishiKeshPathak i cant do that cause there is no thymeleaf-extras-tiles3-spring4 library yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the **TilesConfigurer** class to config a thymeleaf tiles integration ,**TilesConfigurer** is used to config a tiles integration with spring only 
so to config a thymeleaf tiles spring integration you should change the **TilesConfigurer** to **ThymeleafTilesConfigurer** that is in the **org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.spring4.web.configurer** package

thus your method should change to

```
 @Bean
    public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer thymeleafTilesConfigurer(){
        final ThymeleafTilesConfigurer configurer = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-defs.xml" });
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
         return configurer;
    }
```

Hope thats helps

Comment: Oops ,i haven't realize this ,thanks so much its working like a charm now :)